# Code on php not working on javascript

Tags: php, javascript

```
$file =  fopen("teste.php","r");
$members[]="";
$i=0;
while (!feof($file)) {
    $members[] = fgets($file);
    ?>
        <script>
            alert('<?php echo fgets($file); ?>');
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

This is my code, can some tell me why the alert is coming empty?

Comment: What is the contents of "teste.php"?

Comment: what is `fgets($file)`?

Comment: Also, fopen will get the contents of the php file, it won't execute, if that's what you want.

Comment: The syntax for combining php with js in your code looks really rough!

Comment: what do you get if you view source of the page, do you get the script tag and alert with data inside

Comment: If you look at the source code you should be able to see if `fgets($file);` is pulling the contents correctly since the php runs before it outputs to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you mean is that you want an alert to pop up from the browser when the server reaches a certain point in your php code, the answer is "no", you can't

While the server is running your php code, there's no contact with the browser (until the response starts coming back). There are situations in which a server may be streaming content back to the browser, and in such a case it'd be possible to have some agreed-upon convention for the server to mark the content stream with messages to be alerted out immediately, but I don't think that's what you're asking about here.

Comment: Actually, I had some fun with this before. If you're interested, check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) out, you can load a page into the browser, and have it send small script tags that control what the browser does on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

in the script you may be already on EOF.

To get your spected results try

```
  $file =  fopen("teste.php","r");
    $members[]="";
    $i=0;
    while (!feof($file)) {

        ?>
            <script>
                alert('<?php echo fgets($file); ?>');
            </script>
        <?php
    }
```

or

```
  $file =  fopen("teste.php","r");
    $members[]="";
    $i=0;
    while (!feof($file)) {
        $members[] = fgets($file);
        ?>
            <script>
                alert('<?php echo fgets($file); ?>');
            </script>
        <?php
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$members[] = fgets($file);
?>
    <script>
        alert('<?php echo fgets($file); ?>');
    </script>
```

`fgets` moves the internal pointer forward every time it is called. I'm guessing your file is a single line of text.

So it is being read into `$members`, and then the pointer is at the end of the file. Therefore the next call to it (the one being put in the alert) is returning nothing.

Try `$tmp = fgets($file); $members[] = $tmp; ... alert('<?php echo $tmp; ?>');`

Answer (score 0):

> This is my code, can some tell me why the alert is coming empty?

```
<?php

$file =  fopen("teste.php","r");
$members[]="";
$i=0;
while (!feof($file)) 
{
   $line = fgets($file); //move the cursor
   $members[] = $line; 

        echo "<script>";
        echo   "alert($line);";
        echo "</script>";

}

?>
```

Very late I know. I am looking on something that has to do with fopen and thought I'd add the solution because I cam across this by accident.